# Observable object in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have 3 swift classes, ContentView, LogIn and SignUP.
I can t make a boolean var which, let s say, is changing it s value in login.swift, to also announce contentview and signup about the new value.

Bassically, I have account = true, when account became false, i want all 3 classes contentview, login and signup to know that he s value is false now.

Any idea how can I do this? An example with simple 3 views will help me. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What you looking for is @EnvironmentObject. There are many great tutorials and much Information available online. Example: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 view right? ContentView, LogIn and SignUP.  For all of those view you need to pass like

```
SignUP().environmentObject(account)
...
Login().environmentObject(account)
```

and in Views

```
struct LoginView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var account: Bool
    ...
}
struct SignUP: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var account: Bool
    ...
}
```